# Why can't you apply the natural logarithm rule to integrate $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I understand that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, or $\frac{1}{x^2} = x^{-2}$, but why wouldn't you be able anyhow to apply the rule for which $\int \frac{1}{x}dx = \ln{|x|} + C$, and have, for example $\int \frac{1}{x^2}dx = \ln{|x^2|} + C$?

Comment: That would require you to have an integrand of $\frac{1}{x^2} d(x^2)$, that is, $\frac{2}{x} dx$. In other words, the log rule requires the denominator to be the same as what you are integrating with respect to. Another way to see this would be to try to differentiate your proposed antiderivative, you will see that you get the wrong answer.

Comment: Because integrating a product (such as $\frac1x\cdot\frac1x$) is never as straight-forward as one might hope.

Comment: It appears you'd even dare to write $\int x^2\,\mathrm dx=\int\frac1{x^{-2}}\,\mathrm dx = \ln|x^{-2}|+C$, won't you?

Comment: Note that there's no such thing as a "chain rule" for integration; just because $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are integrable, doesn't mean you can use this to integrate $f(g(x))$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Exactly, haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice:

- $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}=x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

So:

$$\int\frac{1}{x^n}\space\text{d}x=\int x^{-n}\space\text{d}x=\frac{x^{1-n}}{1-n}+\text{C}$$

Set $n=\frac{1}{2}$:

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}\space\text{d}x=\int x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\space\text{d}x=\frac{x^{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}}{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}+\text{C}=2\sqrt{x}+\text{C}$$

---

Now if we use the same rule with $n=1$, we get:

$$\int\frac{1}{x^1}\space\text{d}x=\int x^{-1}\space\text{d}x=\frac{x^{1-1}}{1-1}+\text{C}=\frac{x^{0}}{0}+\text{C}$$

$$\color{red}{\text{And we can't divide by}\space0}$$

And if we know $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x}$:

$$\int\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\ln(x)\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x$$

Answer (score 2):

If I well understand you ask why, if we have $F'(x)=f(x)$ than we cannot have:
$$
\int g(f(x)) dx = g(F(x))
$$

You can see that this is impossible by using the chain rule:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}g(F(x))=g'(x)f(x) \ne  g(f(x))
$$
In the same way you can show that

$$
\int f(g(x))dx= F(g(x)) 
$$
does not work.

Comment: Correct. Maybe I should have phrased the question differently, what's not exactly clear is why, indeed, $\frac{d}{dx}\ln{x} = \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: This is a different question. You can see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335506/proving-log-x-using-the-definition-of-derivative

Answer (score 2):

Because that ignores the chain rule.
$$
\frac d {dx} \ln(x^5) = \frac 1 {x^5}\cdot \frac d {dx} x^5 = \frac 1 {x^5} \cdot 5x^4 = \frac 5 x \ne \frac 1 {x^5}.
$$

Notice that one can also do this:
$$
\frac d {dx} \ln (x^5) = \frac d {dx} (5\ln x) = 5\frac d {dx} \ln x = 5\cdot \frac 1 x = \frac 5 x.
$$
If the proposed derivative $\dfrac 1 {x^5}$ were right, then you'd have to wonder why these two methods don't yield identical results.

Answer (score 0):

When integrating any function $f(x)$ you must take into account the variable along which you are integrating, in this case $d x$.

So, according to your rule we can also state that 
\begin{equation}
\int \cos x^2 d x = \sin x^2 + C
\end{equation} 
, since $\displaystyle \int \cos x d x = \sin x + C$

As long as it is incorrect, you should solve these types of integral using various methods such as change of variable to have the "correct" result.

Comment: $\int \frac{1}{x}dx = \int x^{-1}dx = x + C$, with $x \neq 0$, why is this not the case? Or maybe what's really not so clear is, why is $\frac{d}{dx}\ln{x} = \frac{1}{x}$ valid?

Comment: If you google for Taylor expansion, you can expand function $\ln x$ and see what happens when you differentiate it. It will give you result of $\cfrac{1}{x}$

Comment: That would be recursive, since the definition of the Taylor series itself uses derivatives: $\large \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {f^n(c)}{n!} (x-c)^n$

Comment: To answer "why is $\frac{d}{dx} \ln x = \frac{1}{x}$ valid", start with $e^{\ln x} = x$ (for $x > 0$) and differentiate both sides.  The left is, using the chain rule, $e^{\ln x} \cdot \frac{d}{dx} \ln x$ while the right side is $1$.  Remembering that $e^{\ln x} = x$, we may solve for $\frac{d}{dx}\ln x$, getting $\frac{d}{dx} = \frac{1}{e^{\ln x}} = \frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly because x and x^2 are not the same thing. It'll be much better if you rewrite f(x) as x^-2, which will be easier to compute.

Comment: This does not explain OPs question